# Which formats (explictly) does DateTime.TryParse recognise?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm referring to the `DateTime.TryParse(string s, out DateTime result)` overload, which tries to parse a `DateTime` from a string - without a specific format being specified.

I can see from [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that the method uses `DateTimeFormatInfo` (derived from Control Panel settings), and that times are not required, etc.

However, how do I know if it currently and/or will in the future recognise, for example, the following?

- 13-May-14
- 13-May-2014
- 13/05/2014
- 13-05-2014
- 13 May 14

(not an exhaustive list, just a few examples)

I've looked at the source to the method, but reverse engineering to find out expected results from a core .NET method doesn't seem right.

I can see from the documentation, *"...because the DateTime.TryParse(String, DateTime) method tries to parse the string representation of a date and time using the formatting rules of the current culture..."* - is there some other place in MSDN that lists valid potential representations, or which class defines them

Comment: What will you do with such knowledge, and what if the list changes in the future?

Comment: I will know if this method fits my purpose or not.  I would much prefer a set of rules, laws or a description of logic as to which formats are tried or attempted to be parsed, rather than an exhaustive list.  I'm not looking for specific formats to be parsed at all in fact, just to be able to judge that the approach the method takes for parsing is the same one that I would otherwise manually implement

Comment: Maybe if you could tell us what your purpose *is* we could tell you and provide evidence to back it up. About 80% of the time when people are asking a question like this (IME), it turns out that what they probably should be doing is using `TryParseExact` and *specifying* the formats that they want to support.

Comment: My purpose - I need to recognise and parse dates from strings in formats that may be in general use in a target locale.  For example, in the UK, it should parse the formats in my question.  It's a qualitative measurement; I want to be convinced by documentation or comment that in most cases TryParse will do a good attempt at this.  The single documentation page in itself seems a bit vague - hence posting this to find more evidence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

[DateTime.GetDateTimeFormats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fyk2998w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
DateTime july28 = new DateTime(2009, 7, 28, 5, 23, 15, 16);

string[] july28Formats = july28.GetDateTimeFormats();

// Print out july28 in all DateTime formats using the default culture.
foreach (string format in july28Formats) {
    Console.WriteLine(format);
}
```

In real life log the value of any failed TryParse if you need to know what values failed

Cannot post it as it belongs to my company but I wrote a program to extract dates from a text and then parse date.  I wrote regex to extract the date for any of those EN or FR pattern. There were some dates that to me were valid GetAllDateTimePatterns that did not parse.

Comment: That looks very promising - is there any stronger link between this list/method and the TryParse method?  (I can't see one immediately)?

Comment: You can pass an IFormatProvider provider to both GetDateTimeFormats and TryParse.  If you are concerned they do not use IFormatProvider the same then test.  Really generate 1000 dates and write them out in each format and see if they are parsed correctly.

Answer (score 4):

[From the MSDN documentation for `DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx):

> The string to be parsed can take any of the following forms:
>
> - A string with a date and a time component.
> - A string with a date but no time component. If the time component is absent, the method assumes 12:00 midnight. If the date component has a two-digit year, it is converted to a year based on the `Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` of the current culture's current calendar or the specified culture's current calendar (if you use an overload with a non-null *provider* argument).
> - A string with a time but no date component. The method assumes the current date unless you call the `Parse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)` overload and include `DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault` in the *styles* parameter, in which case the method assumes January 1, 0001.
> - A string that includes time zone information and conforms to ISO 8601. In the following examples, the first string designates Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), and the second string designates the time in a time zone that's seven hours earlier than UTC:
>
>   ```
>   2008-11-01T19:35:00.0000000Z 
>   2008-11-01T19:35:00.0000000-07:00
>   ```
> - A string that includes the GMT designator and conforms to the RFC 1123 time format; for example:
>
>   ```
>   Sat, 01 Nov 2008 19:35:00 GMT
>   ```
> - A string that includes the date and time along with time zone offset information; for example:
>
>   ```
>   03/01/2009 05:42:00 -5:00
>   ```

While these docs were written for `Parse`, they also apply to `TryParse`.  Since the documentation for `DateTime.Parse` has much more detail, you might think that `Parse` is the primary method and `TryParse` is a wrapper around parse - *but actually, the inverse is true*.  `Parse` wraps `TryParse` and throws an exception when it receives `false`.  [Source here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs#2243).

When these docs refer to a "date component" or a "time component", they are specifically talking about one of the formats provided by the `DateTimeFormatInfo` object that is passed to the `IFormatProvider` parameter - or one derived from the `CultureInfo` passed, or from the `CurrentCulture` if none was provided.

If you want to know all of the formats for a particular `DateTimeFormatInfo` object, then you can use [`DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aszyst2c.aspx).  For example:

```
string[] p = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();
```

As specific example, consider:

```
var dtfi = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB").DateTimeFormat;
foreach (string pattern in dtfi.GetAllDateTimePatterns())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(pattern);
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
dd/MM/yyyy
dd/MM/yy
d/M/yy
d.M.yy
yyyy-MM-dd
dd MMMM yyyy
d MMMM yyyy
dddd, d MMMM yyyy
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy
dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm
dd MMMM yyyy H:mm
dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt
dd MMMM yyyy h:mm tt
d MMMM yyyy HH:mm
d MMMM yyyy H:mm
d MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt
d MMMM yyyy h:mm tt
dddd, d MMMM yyyy HH:mm
dddd, d MMMM yyyy H:mm
dddd, d MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt
dddd, d MMMM yyyy h:mm tt
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy H:mm
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy h:mm tt
dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd MMMM yyyy H:mm:ss
dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dd MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt
d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
d MMMM yyyy H:mm:ss
d MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
d MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
dddd, d MMMM yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, d MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, d MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
dd/MM/yyyy H:mm
dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt
dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt
dd/MM/yy HH:mm
dd/MM/yy H:mm
dd/MM/yy hh:mm tt
dd/MM/yy h:mm tt
d/M/yy HH:mm
d/M/yy H:mm
d/M/yy hh:mm tt
d/M/yy h:mm tt
d.M.yy HH:mm
d.M.yy H:mm
d.M.yy hh:mm tt
d.M.yy h:mm tt
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
yyyy-MM-dd H:mm
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt
yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss
dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss
dd/MM/yy H:mm:ss
dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt
dd/MM/yy h:mm:ss tt
d/M/yy HH:mm:ss
d/M/yy H:mm:ss
d/M/yy hh:mm:ss tt
d/M/yy h:mm:ss tt
d.M.yy HH:mm:ss
d.M.yy H:mm:ss
d.M.yy hh:mm:ss tt
d.M.yy h:mm:ss tt
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt
yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss tt
d MMMM
d MMMM
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
HH:mm
H:mm
hh:mm tt
h:mm tt
HH:mm:ss
H:mm:ss
hh:mm:ss tt
h:mm:ss tt
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd MMMM yyyy H:mm:ss
dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dd MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt
d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
d MMMM yyyy H:mm:ss
d MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
d MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
dddd, d MMMM yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, d MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, d MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, dd MMMM yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM yyyy
MMMM yyyy
```

Ideally, any string in any of the format patterns returned from this method would be considered valid when using `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.TryParse`.

**HOWEVER** - as Blam pointed out in comments, not every possible format will parse correctly.  The problem is simply that not all formats can roundtrip for every value.  For example, the `en-US` culture has both `MM/dd/yy` and `yy/MM/dd` formats.  If I parse `14/05/01`, you would think that it would recognize 14 as a year since it is too large to be a month and use the `yy/MM/dd` format.  But in reality, it sees three two-digit numbers separated by slashes and thus chooses the first entry that matches, which is `MM/dd/yy`.  Then since 14 doesn't fit into `MM`, parsing fails and `TryParse` returns false.

Comment: Not agreeing with the conclusion that any GetAllDateTimePatterns will TryParse correctly.  The documentation does not explicitly state that and from the implementation I am not seeing that it parses based on GetAllDateTimePatterns.

Comment: @Blam - I think you are correct.  I ran through all cultures and all formats and there are many failures.  A lot of them have to do with using two-digit years.  For example, `en-US` has a format of `yy/MM/dd`, but using `Parse`, it's indistinguishable from `MM/dd/yy`.

Comment: I think you owe me a +1

Comment: Was the first thing I did before I wrote my answer at all. :)

Comment: @Kieren - in case of tie, I yield to Blam.

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing I can find is this:

http://www.basicdatepicker.com/samples/cultureinfo.aspx

Note that the culture sensitivity is used so that you can deploy your application to any culture/region of the world, and if they enter a date in a format that is expected for that culture, it can be "universally parsed". The goal is to allow you to be able to process input from multiple cultures, versus code specifically for a particular culture and format (as you potentially seem to be doing here).

Comment: Thank you, but this is a list of formats in different locales and does not describe the approach, rules, or logic that TryParse uses.  I am aware that different locales have different formats, and where to find them - looking for some description of the TryParse logic here

Comment: Pretty sure it boils down to kernel/COM calls, not likely for you to find them easily.

Comment: It doesn't seem so from the reference source implementation; I have no idea why the kernel would be involved in this, either.  Definitely a user-mode thing!  There is a lot of code in the reference source - I want to know what the driver, spec or intention was in the (fairly complex) logic in there.

Comment: What I don't understand is WHY. The culture-specific format is an *implementation detail*, not something to hard-code to in most cases. It's a lot like how a keypad is laid out differently in different countries. Do you care? Either way you still receive the numeric input in the end.

Comment: I want to know if the method's purpose is "parse common date/time formats in the target locale" or "parse a few specific date/time formats in a few locales".  In the first case, I use it - in the second, I write code myself.  I'm asking for answers to my question, not a question back.  If you don't know the answer, please consider not answering!

Comment: It is the former, using the user/computer's locale.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone Your are not sure what "using the formatting rules of the current culture" means?  Then test.  Pass 1/31/2001 and 31/1/2001 to DateTime.TryParse(string s, out DateTime result).